# Apache SPARK: which SQL operations can only be executed by Spark via moving all data to one partition?

Tags: apache-spark

We know that some operations in Spark can be executed in parallel. For example, when spark joins or groups datasets - it is doing so in parallel after reshuffle.

Other operations can probably be done in parallel: for example, simple sorting. I guess spark reshuffles data by sorting key and thus produces a sorted distributed dataset.

Now we come to window operations. There is a well-known warning about window operations:

> WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all
> data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance
> degradation.

This means that we are running Window operation on the whole dataset, instead of on partitioned dataset. Looks like Spark definitely cannot execute such command without moving all data to same partition.

Bottom line, here is the table I want to fill:

| operation | prepartition technique to speed up | single partition operation by design |
| --- | --- | --- |
| join | partition by join key | NO |
| groupBy with some aggregate function | partition by groupby key | NO |
| rownumber with partition by | partition by partition key | NO |
| rownumber without partition by | - | YES |
| sort | partition by sorting key | NO |
| min/max | - | NO |

Any lines with YES in last column to add?
Are my assumptions about partitioning in advance correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **join** - `single partition operation by design` : It depends on the data as well. Imagine if your join key is highly skewed or all of them are same. All will be brought to Single partition
- **join** - `prepartition technique to speed up` : yes you can repartition first and then join. But essentially Spark will anyway do that repartition even if you don't enforce it.
- **groupBy** - `prepartition technique to speed up` : **No this is wrong**. It can probably slow things. groupBy first aggregates within a partition then shuffles the aggregated data( smaller records ). If you partition manually first, it will shuffle all data without aggregation and then aggregate
- **window with partition** - Again if the data is highly skewed or all are same key , then it will be brought to single partition even though there is no warning.

A table like might be a guideline but in most cases, our logic handling depends on the nature of the data.

Comment: thank a lot! What about min/max operations? Will spark move everything to single partition in this case?

Comment: Nope. It will calculate min/max within a partition first, then move the calculated records only.